# Horizontal List Issues

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a horizontal list that uses vh or vw, or percentages for padding. So that it auto-scales to window without js. I'm not worried about backwards compatibility so much. However, whenever I do, there is always a gap between list items.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3f7P/

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display: block` to your links - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3f7P/2/)

```css
ul#topMenu li a:link, #topMenu li a:link {
    color: #7C7C7C;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #252525;
    border-right: 1px solid #313131;
    padding: 1vh 2vw;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 2vw;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Xarcell - If this is the best solution, feel free to "Accept" it by clicking the checkmark.  This, and upvotes, are the best way to show your appreciation on Stack Overflow.